# PHP setrlimit error with Paypal IPN data capture script

Tags: php, email, paypal, paypal-ipn, setrlimit

So I have an IPN data capture script that has been working fine for months. No problems at all. Recently I added an email function to send my customers emails. Those emails worked great for about 15-20 days or so. I catch on that orders are not getting into the database correctly and checked it out. Now I'm at a loss.

I have several setrlimit errors Operation not permitted in my log from the file. However, it stopped throwing them. I dumped my log to see if it was an issue with the log being full or something and still nothing. Paypal is sending the messages and not kicking back an error. It will usually give a 502 error if something is up. So the script is capturing it but not data ends up in my database and no email is sent. I'm still CCed on those so I should see them. I'm kinda at a loss.

Any ideas?

Am I screwing up the email code and not closing something and filling up a buffer? How do I change it? Thoughts?